# SSO b/w cognos and websphere portal

Tags: single-sign-on, cognos, websphere-portal, cognos-10

I know we can enable SS b/w Cognos and WebSphere portal server using LTPA token or Shared secret. I know the steps to do to achieve this SSO, but If I am not using the cognos portlets in websphere portal, would the SSO work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes SSO will still work. You can confirm this by logging into Portal and then pointing the same browser session to cognos.  You should be automatically logged in as long as the LTPA Token is shared and portal and cognos are using the same LDAP.

Comment: Thank you Matt for the reply, I am planning to have links to cognos report in a portlet by using anchor tags, will the SOO still work?, I know I need to try this but just wanted to confirm so that I am on right track.

Comment: Yes it should still work as it will pass the LTPA token as part of the redirect and do the lookup with the tokens as part of the lookup